# Installation of Apache on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, virtualhost

How to install Apache on a CentOS 7?

Comment: Voting to migrate to server fault.

Answer (score 2):

1) login as root or use `sudo`

2) yum install `-y httpd` or `sudo yum install -y httpd`

3)all config files are locates in `/etc/httpd/conf` and `/etc/httpd/conf.d`

4)all your html files can be found in `/var/www/html`

5) Start learning the basic at http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-httpd.html

6) grab a cup of coffee, tea or whatever you like most.

Answer (score 0):

Or just edit your /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf near the bottom and voila you have a new vhost!